# base64 to reduce digits required to encode a decimal number

Tags: c++, base64

I have to manage an ID of some objects.
I need these ID be unique.
I have the constraint that these ID can't be too long in term of digits required

Is base64 is a nice way to reduce the number of digits required to encoding an ID ?

EDIT:

```
langage : c++
data type : integer , then convert in a std::string
```

Comment: Letting us know what language you are using, and what data type (.Net `System.Decimal`? C `float`? Fixed-point?) you mean would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each character in Base64 can represent 6 bits, so divide your ID length by 6 to see how many characters it will be. Binary data is 8 bits per byte so it will always be shorter, but the bytes won't all be readable.

Base64 will make the ID readable, but it still won't be good if the ID needs to be hand entered, like a key. For that you'll want to restrict the character set further.

Comment: I generated programatically the ID. they never need to be hand entered

Comment: @Guillaume07, just saw your edit from a few days ago. Assuming a 32-bit integer, you will need 6 Base64 characters, 8 base16 (hex) characters, or 10 decimal digits. This is in place of 4 binary bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is a nice way to transport binary data over ASCII. It doesn't usually decrease the size of anything. In my experience it increases it by <del>66%</del> 33% (thanks for the correction).

Comment: Base64 stores 3 bytes of data in 4 bytes. That's a 33% increase.

Comment: @hammar: I knew it was a nice round number like that ;)

Comment: ok I am just surprised that base16 decrease size but base64 increase

Comment: base16 is a 100% increase. Base 16 can represent 16 different states with one char. One char is 8 bits, but you only need 4 binary bits to represent 16 states.

Comment: @Guillaume07: I think you're comparing to decimal representation, i.e. "Base10". All of Base16, 32, and 64 will be improvements over that. Chris is talking about pure bytes, i.e. "Base256", which is the smallest, but is not well suited for displaying/printing.

Answer (score 1):

If you care just about the length of the output string and not the actual byte size. Then by converting  from decimal numeric system (base 10) to any numerical system with base higher then 10 the output string will be shorter
see example here 
http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/octal-to-decimal/

for example in their case
decimal 9999999999   <- 10 chars long
in base 32 numerical system
will be 4LDQPDR      <- 7 chars long

with up to 95 printable ascii charecters you could use your own 
base 95 numerical system and get even shorter string

used this approach in one of my projects and it was enough to squeeze "long" numerical ids in short string fields